# Why does this property return 'undefined'?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know the question title is very general so I'll give the details.

Component:

```
export class MaterialDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  originalMaterialsData: Material[];
  currentMaterialData: Material[];

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute, public dataService:DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let id = +this._route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.dataService.getMaterialData().subscribe((response) => {
      this.originalMaterialsData = response;
    });

    for(let i = 0; i < this.originalMaterialsData.length; i++) {
      if(this.originalMaterialsData[i].id = id) {
        this.currentMaterialData.push(this.originalMaterialsData[i]);
      }
    }

  }


}
```

I'm trying to get the matched object with an id from `originalMaterialsData` (array of objects) and assign it to `currentMaterialData` so that I'm able to use this one particular object in my component. But it keeps returning `undefined` even though I tried many ways to differently write it.

Comment: Did you try to put the `for`-loop into your `subscribe` block?

Comment: It is because getMaterialData() is async. So your code first goes in the for loop before it gets the data

Comment: Also [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](//stackoverflow.com/q/23667086) and [Waiting for an observable to finish](//stackoverflow.com/q/43366694)

Comment: That's right. I totally forgot that my function was async. I made that part async as well and it works! Thanks @StephanStrate and fawee